# how to find any document in database with an object id with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find, mongoose, objectid

I have some relational records in some collections. I use object ids for this. And I want to find an object with without collection find functions.

Is it possible to use a global find function on db like this?

```
db.globalfind({_id:"12345678901234567890"});
```

Comment: Mongoose just wraps the native mongo nodejs driver. However, there's no such thing as a cross collection global find function in MongoDb.

Answer (score 2):

Operations in MongoDB only always work on one collection. If you want to do a find on multiple collections, then you need to run multiple queries - one per collection. Of course, it's quite for Mongoose to implement a convenience function for that, but I don't think it has, or should, as it is against one of MongoDB's paradigms.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't really support getting an arbitrary document based on it's objectID. However you can use the code below that searches the entire database:

```
var objectID = ObjectId("53623db53004e212edcc8fe6");
var findMultiple = true;

// ----------------------- code -----------------------
var stack = [];
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName) {
    var docs = db.getCollection(collName).find(); 
    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        doc._FROM = collName;
        stack.push(doc);
    });
});

while(stack.length > 0) {
    var doc = stack.pop();
    if(doc._id) {
        if(doc._id.toString() === objectID.toString()) {
            print(doc);
            if(!findMultiple) {
                stack = [];
            }
        }
    }
    for (var property in doc) {
        var value = doc[property];
        var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
        if (type === '[object Object]' || type === '[object Array]' || type ==='[object bson_object]') {
            value._FROM = doc._FROM + "/" + property;
            stack.push(value);
        }
    }
}
```